# I am doing unit testing using gtest and gmock frameworks and I need help in stubbing/mocking a external C functions used inside class functions

Tags: c++, unit-testing, googletest, googlemock

So I am trying to write test cases for my production code but the coverage is drastically low due to the usage of some external C library which cannot be executed without target hardware, So I have no choice but to stub the same.  Now the problem is how to stub a C function ?

My production code : prod_code.cpp

```
 int TargetTestClass::targetFunc()
 {
    if(externalCFunc() == True)
    {
        statement1; statement2; statement3; /// and so on
    }
 }
```

My testcode.cpp generally contains tests like this

```
//Fixture for Target Test class
class TargetTestClassFixture : public testing::Test {
      TargetTestClass* targetTestClassPtr;
      void SetUp() {
         targetTestClassPtr = new TargetTestClass();
      }
      void TearDown() {
         delete targetTestClassPtr;
      }
  };



TEST_F (unitTest, test_001)
  {
       targetTestClassPtr->targetFunc(); //Need to do something here so that externalCFunc() returns true on call
  }
```

Comment: An approach we have used for such instances is to generate our own version of the external library with stubbed out functions.  These stubbed versions should have means for controlling/setting results.  If you compile with your includes/linking pointing at your stubbed versions

Comment: @kreynolds The problem with this approach will be that I have been provided a library which includes this C library, Now I am bound to use that library as it is. If I will redefine a C function then it would create linking ambiguities right?

Comment: Not necessarily.  It sounds like the library you are given you cannot change.  However in your Test executable you should have control over what your include search path looks like and the version of a library you are linking against.  

In your test environment the "real" version of the library would simply not be linked, your include search path would be different as well.  Therefore when you compile the Unit Test the only version of the library it knows about is your stubbed version

Comment: @kreynolds let me rephrase what I wanted to say. I have been provided a library libCmn.so which contains implementations for externalFunc() as well as targetFunc, now if I don't link libCmn.so to my test executable then it won't find targetFunc as well, so  I would end up redefining entire production code right?

Comment: It depends on the extent of your Unit Tests.  You only need to stub out the function definitions from libCmn that are directly used by the Test or specific application under test.  Over time there may be many, many stub functions in your "Test" version of libCmn, but to get up and running usually it is not too bad.  Functions that you do not need for the specific code you are testing can be completely empty, and properly stubbed when they are actually needed for testing.

Comment: @kreynolds Frankly speaking there will be quite a lot of functions over time that would need stubbing. This looks like an Idea and worth implementing. However, this is too tedious and messy way of getting it done. I was looking for something neat like ExpectCall(obj, func) type. However, Thanks a lot for the suggestion.

Comment: In that case....it may be worth investigating this library which I believe supports free standing functions: https://github.com/apriorit/gmock-global.  It looks pretty interesting, but not a lot of love yet so user beware.

Comment: @kreynolds This is indeed interesting, However I am not sure if this can be integrated to work side by side with the CPP tests, for example,

`TEST_F (TestGlobal, CanMultiplyGlobal)
{
    EXPECT_GLOBAL_CALL(externalCFunc, externalCFunc(1, 2)).Times(1);
    targetTestClassPtr->targetFunc(); //would calling through pointer of mock invokes FFF fuction call ??
}`

Comment: based on your final answer below I take it GMOCK_GLOBAL worked ok for you?

Comment: @kreynolds Yes, thank you for pointing me to the direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found 2 solutions to my problem so I am going to answer the same here.

Solution 1 : This involved changing the target source code. Basically you need to write a wrapper that calls the external C functions like below

```
Class TargetTestClass{
    protected:
        int targetFunc();
        virtual int externalCFuncWrapper();  // Wrapper
};

//call the external C function from the wrapper
int TargetTestClass::externalCFunctionWrapper(){
    return(externalCFunc());
}

//Definition of targetFuc in original question

//Now write a mock class for Target Test Class as usual and mock the wrapper function to return what you want to 

class MockTargetTestClass : public TargetTestClass{
    public: MOCK_METHOD0(externalCFunctionWrapper, int());
};

//Now use the Mock class as needed
TEST_F ( TargetUnitTest, TestingExternalCFuctionCall)
{
    MockTargetTestClass mockTargetTestClassObj;
    using ::testing::Return;
    using ::testing::_;
    Expect_Call(mockTargetTestClassObj, externalCFunctionWrapper())
    .WillOnce(Return(1));

    Assert_EQ(mockTargetTestClassObj.targetFunc(), 1);
}
```

Solution 2 : Thanks to @kreynolds, I have looked into Fake Function Framework and implemented as follows :

```
Class TargetTestClass{
    protected:
        int targetFunc();
        //No Code change needed in target source code
};

//In testcode.cpp 

#include <gmock-global/gmock-global.h>

MOCK_GLOBAL_FUNC0(externalCFunc, int());

TEST( Unittest, test002){
    using ::testing::Return;
    using ::testing::_;
    EXPECT_GLOBAL_CALL(externalCFunc, externalCFunc()).WillOnce(Return(1));

    TargetTestClass targetFunc; //This does not contain any wrapper
    EXPECT_EQ(targetTestClassObj.targetFunc(), 1);
}
```

I am using the second solution as this does not require any change in my source code and easier to use.

Once again thank you everyone for giving your time.

Answer (score 2):

What you can do is to create a source file like my_c_stubs.c where you rudimentary implement your C function. For example, the implementation can just return true. Then don't link original source file with the external C function but rather use your stub file. You should still use the original C header. In this way you won't be able to stub inline functions though. If it is required, some more sophisticated approach is needed.

Comment: Note: sometimes it is best you create a `my_c_stubs.h` as well and use that as the include.  The 3rd party library could potentially have function definitions, extern values, additional includes, etc that you will not want as dependencies for your test.